# Transfer code from controller to repository doesn't work properly

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to clean up my code a little bit and create well-organized code.

I'm trying to transfer some functions that are related to the database from my controller to my repository.

Unfortunately, some functionality was lost due to my changes.

Specifically, the method that looks for existing emails

**The old Code - controller (works but not organized):**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Register(RegisterDto registerDto)
    {
        if (await _userRepository.UserExists(registerDto.Email))
        { 
            return BadRequest("The Email is already in use"); 
        }

        // rest of the code
    }
```

**The repository**

```
    public async Task<bool> UserExists(string email)
    {
        return await _userManager.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.Email == email.ToLower());
    }
```

**What I have tried - controller: (organized but not working as intended**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Register(RegisterDto registerDto)
    {
        await _userRepository.UserExists(registerDto.Email);

    // rest of the code
    }
```

**The repository**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> UserExists(string email)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.Email == email.ToLower());

        if (user =! false)
        {
            return BadRequest("The Email is already in use");
        }
        
        return Ok();
    }
```

The issue is that in the case of an existing email, The app keeps running and doesn't throw the error - "The Email is already in use"

What am I doing wrong here? And why does it happen?

Comment: It looks like from the repository once you get back BadRequest("..."), you are not storing it in a variable and returning it from your controller

Comment: Your first solution was much better.

Comment: @anand_v.singh thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user =! false
```

This is not an evaluation, it's an assignment. What you are doing here is:

```
user = !false
```

In other words:

```
user = true
```

In other words you are not *checking* if `user` is `true`, you are **setting** user to `true`

What you want here is

```
if (user)
{
    return BadRequest("The Email is already in use");
}
```

The second issue here is that your repository does `return BadRequest("The Email is already in use");`, but your controller never does anything with the returned value:

```
await _userRepository.UserExists(registerDto.Email);
```

To work, this should be:

```
return await _userRepository.UserExists(registerDto.Email);
```

However, the new code you wrote here introduced problems that did not exist before.

- `user` is not a great name. `userExists` would be better.
- A repository should never return `BadRequest`, that's a controller's job.
- It's unclear to me why you rewrote `UserExists` to begin with. It was doing its correct job, and you've somehow now foisted the controller's responsibility into the repository, which is introducing a mistake and not solving one.

I am convinced that the changes you made to the code need to be undone. The old code is actually well written. What you've done with it is introducing issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! This is such an AMAZING explanation! I was trying to make a clear separation between the code and the database.